# SQL about view and null

Tags: sql, view, null

I have the following tables:
STUDENT which includes 'sid' from 1 to 11
where sid means "student id"
and
ENROLLED which includes 'cnum' and 'sid'
where cnum means "course number".
Table ENROLLED only has sid from 1 to 10, 11 is NOT in ENROLLED

Now I want to create a view that shows 'sid' and their corresponding 'cnum'
if I write like this

```
create view VIEWA as
select S1.sid, E1.cnum
from STUDENT S1, ENROLLED E1
where S1.sid=E1.sid
order by S1.sid;
```

The result will be something like this

```
sid   cnum
1      **
1      **
2      **
.
.
.
10     **
```

you can see that 'sid' 11 is not in the result. However what I expect is this

```
sid   cnum
1      **
1      **
2      **
.
.
.
10     **
11    null
```

I want this "null" to be shown. I know the method might be stupidly simple, but our professor didn't teach us this..... please help. thank you!!

Comment: You need to use an OUTER JOIN.  Google that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
create view VIEWA as
select S1.sid, E1.cnum
from STUDENT S1 LEFT JOIN ENROLLED E1
on S1.sid=E1.sid
order by S1.sid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a [`LEFT OUTER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

```
CREATE VIEW VIEWA 
AS

SELECT S1.sid, E1.cnum
FROM STUDENT S1
LEFT OUTER JOIN ENROLLED E1
    ON S1.sid=E1.sid
ORDER BY S1.sid;
```

That will include *all* rows from `S1` (even if there is not a match) and *matching* rows from `E1`